# C++ Issue using overloaded operator on a pointer: expected unqualified-id error

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, operator-overloading

I'm having a hard time figuring out what is going wrong and how to resolve it.
I'm using an overloaded array subscript operator ([]) of a Class through a pointer, but I'm receiving the compiler error: expected unqualified-id
with the following statements

```
if (!(books->[i].isEmpty()) && books->[i].getIsbn() == ISBNnumber) {
                    if (numBooks <= books->[i].getQty()) {
                        listToPrint.push_back(books->[i]);
                        qntyPurchased.push_back(numBooks);
                        books->[i].setQty(books->[i].getQty() - numBooks);
                    } else {
                        cout << "\nThere aren't enough copies to fulfill this order.\n\n";
                    }
                    foundFlag = true;
                    break;
                }
```

For reference, 'books' is class member that stores a pointer to the instance of another class.

```
class Menu {
private:
// Pointer to a bookCollection object
static BookCollection *books;
}

class BookCollection
{
static const int MAX_BOOKS = 20;
BookData book[MAX_BOOKS]; // array of BookData objects
int findBook(string);

public:
BookData &operator[](const int i) { return book[i];
}
```

I was expecting for the compiler to treat it as just another pointer with an array subscript operator, but it's not working.
It works if I use the call to the operator function,
    (books->operator.isEmpty())
But I was trying to avoid this to have cleaner code.

Looking for any suggestions to resolve the error: expected unqualified-id

Comment: `books->[i].isEmpty()` -> `books[i].isEmpty()`?

Comment: @wlovo  It seems you mean books->operator[]( i ).isEmpty(). Or ( *books )[i].isEmpty()

Comment: books[i].isEmpty does not work, but (*books)[i].isEmpty does. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example this expression (and other similar expressions)

```
books->[i].isEmpty()
```

is syntactically invalid.

Instead use

```
books->operator []( i).isEmpty()
```

or

```
( *books )[i].isEmpty()
```

Here is a simplified demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    class BookData
    {
    public:
        bool isEmpty() { return true;  }
    };

    class BookCollection
    {
        BookData book[10]; // array of BookData objects

    public:
        BookData & operator[](size_t i) 
        {
            return book[i];
        }

        const BookData & operator[](size_t i) const
        {
            return book[i];
        }
    };

    class Menu 
    {
    public:
        BookCollection *books;
    };

    BookCollection b;
    Menu m = { &b };

    if (m.books->operator[](0).isEmpty())
    {
        std::cout << "It works!" << std::endl;
    }

    if ( (*m.books)[0].isEmpty())
    {
        std::cout << "And this one works!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Its output is

```
It works!
And this one works!
```

Answer (score 1):

Your statement `books->[i].isEmpty()` is syntactically wrong. As your operator `[]` in `BookCollection` returns a reference to a `BookData`-object out of the internal array, you will have to use the operator in the following way:

```
books[i].isEmpty() && books[i].getIsbn()
```

(Assuming that `BookData` provides methods `isEmpty()` and `getIsbn()`, of course.)

See the following working example:

```
struct Foo {
    int getX() { return x; }
    int x=0;
};

class BookCollection
{
    static const int MAX_BOOKS = 20;
    Foo book[MAX_BOOKS]; // array of BookData objects

public:
    Foo &operator[](const int i) { return book[i];  }
};

int main() {
   BookCollection *b = new BookCollection();
   int x = ((*b)[10]).getX();
}
```

Comment: I originally used books[i], but it gave me an error about books not having a the functions .isEmpty or .getIsbn, which do exist in BookData. It seemed like it was using BookCollections for the functions, so I had to use books->operator[](i) instead.

Comment: It's not working on my side. It should be a reference to the BookData class, but the compiler displays "Class BookCollection doesn't have function 'isEmpty'".

Comment: Ah  - OK. I oversaw that you are using a pointer to a `BookCollection`. See adapted answer - though Vlad  has answered this already.